# How can I export lodash from my Angular module?

Tags: angular, angular-module

I would like to make a generic module that has a bunch of utility methods, including moment and lodash functionality.  I've imported lodash and typed it and I can access it from my components as long as I include the code:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
```

However, I'd like to make this more generic so I can just import my Utils module and have both lodash and moment (as well as a few custom functions) available without having to import these individually in every component.

I've got the following code:

```
import { Injectable, NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import * as _ from "lodash";
import * as _ from "moment";

@Injectable()
@NgModule({
    exports: [_, moment]
})
export class Utils { }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Build:Argument of type '{ exports: LoDashStatic[] 1>; }' 
   is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'
```

Edit: What I'd like to do is this:

```
import { _, moment } from "./Utils.module";
```

instead of

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
import * as moment from "moment";
```

How can I accomplish this?

Edit: Made the code reflect more of what I'd like to accomplish...

Comment: how can you use both decorators? `@Injectable` and `@NgModule` ? Also, lodash is a library and it is not a module

Comment: @Aravind I don't know... is that bad?  It seemed to be working without the lodash stuff.

Comment: ok. tell me what is that you are trying to achieve I will help you out

Comment: In my component, I would like to be able to do import { _, moment } from "../../app.common/utils.service"; and use lodash and moment from a single module instead of importing each one.  I thought my code above would do this, but I get an error.

Comment: you can import lodash and service from the respective files. But you cannot use the above code. as every decorator in angular expects a class for it.

Comment: Dang.  Okay, thanks anyways.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142987/discussion-between-aravind-and-scottie).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
@NgModule({
    exports: [_, moment]
})
...
```

won't work (and thanks to TypeScript, it can detect the issue with type checking), because `exports` contains for *Angular* modules, while these are *ES6* modules:

```
import { _, moment } from "./Utils.module";
```

Instead, it may be not .module.ts file, which are conventionally used for Angular modules, but utils.ts:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
import * as moment from "moment";
export { _, moment };
```

And usually the one should never want to have a separate 'util' file to import third-party packages from it like `import { _, moment } from "./utils"`. The path is relative and needs to be maintained in each file where it is imported. The paths to the packages are not, that's their major advantage.

The whole thing looks like modular antipattern. You won't see this in well-designed projects, because it makes little sense. I would personally recommend to not do this, unless you are really sure what are your benefits here.